# Set Circle Transparency to Vector

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot points on a map. Setting the radius size to a vector is simple. How would I set the transparency according to a vector (column of the plotted point data)?

```
points(myData$Longitude, myData$Latitude, pch = 20, col = colors, cex = myData$Magnitude / 3, lwd = .3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the alpha value in when you create the colors.

```
x = 1:100
y = 1:100
Fade = rgb(1,0,0,seq(0.01,1,0.01))
plot(x,y, pch=20, col=Fade)
```

The fourth argument to `rgb` is the alpha value.

[image: Changing alpha]

Comment: why do you put three values in the `seq()`?

Comment: Start = 0.01, End = 1, by = 0.01  - by is the stepsize.   I wanted 0.01, 0.02, ...